# Cannot boot Ubuntu 16.04 on a mining rig with 6 GPUs, AMD 970 motherboard

Tags: 16.04, boot, kernel

I can run 6+ GPUs mining rigs successfully on any Intel motherboard under Ubuntu 16.04, however with AMD 970 motherboards, only 5 GPUs work. If I install the 6th GPU, the system boots, then I can see the GRUB menu, but very shortly after that I end up with a blinking cursor. Obviously, I am not even getting to booting the kernel.

How can I troubleshoot this, at least to find out the cause?

thank you.

Comment: If I'm remembering it correctly, that was the chipset with an IOMMU issue. It may need an additional boot parameter. I suggest googling your motherboard's model + Ubuntu, maybe something interesting comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding `iommu=soft` to *GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT* in */etc/default/grub* file. Also need to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

```
jj@RIG12:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
```